# Image.Tag of picture Box not working in if statement

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am making a memory game that compares two cards against themselves to see if they are the same. I do this by comparing the tag of the image in the picture box. All of the images have unique tags, however, when compared in an if statement, it passes over and treats it as false. This is the code for when the card is clicked on.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image temp = Boxes[0];
        pictureBox1.Tag = Boxes[0].Tag;
        pictureBox1.Image = temp;
        if (openBox1 == null)
        {
            openBox1 = pictureBox1;
        }
        else if (openBox1 != null && openBox2 == null)
        {
            openBox2 = pictureBox1;
        }
        if (openBox1 != null && openBox2 != null)
        {
            if (openBox1.Image.Tag == openBox2.Image.Tag)
            {
                openBox1 = null;
                openBox2 = null;
            }
            else
            {
                openBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.card;
                openBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.card;
                openBox1 = null;
                openBox2 = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I am tagging the images:

```
List<int> Repeats = new List<int>();
        int random;
        bool test;
        foreach (Image n in Album)//checks to see if image has been added 
        {
            test = true;
            while (test)
            {
                random = randy.Next(0, 16);


                if (!Repeats.Contains(random))
                {
                    Boxes[random] = n;
                    Boxes[random].Tag = n.Width * n.Height;
                    Repeats.Add(random);
                    test = false;
                }
            }

        }
```

I have stepped into the program for myself, and monitored the variables. When I click two of the same card it just ignores that they are the same value.

Comment: `Tag` has type `object`. When you write `if (...Tag == ...Tag)` you compare _references_, not _values_.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov so would I first have to convert the tag values to an int for it to work? Or is it impossible to do it in this way.

Comment: Yes, convert/cast `Tag` to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't works because boxing. `int` is a value type, to cast it to `object` (the type accepted by `Tag`) .net wraps the value type with a new `object` ('boxes' it). As `object` is a reference type and each tag has a different object the equality is not satisfied.

To make it work you must unbox the value, via a type cast or using the operator `as`:

```
//Unbox values before comparing
if (openBox1.Image.Tag as integer == openBox2.Image.Tag as integer)
    //...
```